# identification of embedded shared libraries

Tags: embedded, arm, version, shared-library

I'm looking for a way to identify shared libraries of embedded devices.I'm especially interested in which version a library is used. So far I try to identify a library by either its file name or the soname of the library. Unfortunately most of the libraries don't have detailed version information in there file name or soname.

So I was wondering if there is maybe a database of all available shared libraries for embedded devices which contains in the best case the library name, the version string and some sort of hash.

If you can think of any other reliable way to identify a given shared library I would be really thankful.

Comment: There is no easy way to do that.  Some libraries have functions that return version, and sometimes `strings libmumble.so` can help.  Most of the time however if you can't infer the version from the soname you're basically out of luck.

Comment: thanks for the information. Unfortunately `strings` is in that case not really an option since I have to do that for a ton of libraries.